# Was the homing beacon ever removed from the Falcon?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

In the novelization of *Star Wars: The Force Awakens* Unkar Plutt runs into Rey at Maz's place due to a covert Imperial Homing Beacon, which he says is old technology.

Is this beacon the same one that Tarkin put on there those many years before, or was a new one added in between the events of *A New Hope* and *The Force Awakens*?

Comment: disney canon or legends?

Comment: @phantom42 canon if possible, I'm listening to the audiobook right now and it came upon that scene so I was a little confused.

Comment: My original only has a c-canon answer, but the question is identical.

Comment: We're both asking what happened to the tracking device Tarkin put on the ship.

Comment: This has the makings of a unique question, but *as written* it's a dupe.